# SQL JOIN as single row with child values as columns and ability to ORDER BY child relationship value

Tags: mysql

I don't know what the right definition of this is, but its more dynamic than a regular relationship join.

**contacts:**

```
id, first_name, last_name
```

**fields:**

```
id, handle, type
```

**field_values:**

```
id, field_id, contact_id, value
```

*The table fields is not that important in this, but wanted to give context.*

**Example of contacts table:**

```
id   first_name   last_name
--   -----        --------
1    John         Doe
2    Jane         Smith
```

**Example of field value table:**

```
id   contact_id   field_id   value
--   -----        --------   ------
1    1            1          Boston
2    1            2          johndoe@mail.com
3    2            1          Seattle
3    2            2          janesmith@mail.com
```

In this basic example, you can see that there are 2 fields, one for location (boston, seattle) and one for email. When I put them into a JOIN query they look like this

```
SELECT * FROM contacts LEFT JOIN field_values ON contacts.id = field_values.contact_id;
```

**Example of contacts JOIN field values table:**

```
id   first_name   last_name  field_id  value
--   -----        --------   ------    -------
1    John         Doe        1         Boston
1    John         Doe        2         johndoe@mail.com
2    Jane         Smith      1         Seattle
2    Jane         Smith      2         janesmith@mail.com
```

**TWO QUESTIONS:**

**1)** How do I ORDER BY the field value. So I want to order by the field email which is field id = 2.

**2)** Is it possible to get a single row for each contact and each field value as a new column?

**Example: Single row per contact?**

```
id   first_name   last_name  field_id(2)          field_id(1)
--   -----        --------   ------               -------
1    John         Doe        johndoe@mail.com     Boston
2    Jane         Smith      janesmith@mail.com   Seattle
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single row per contact:

```
SELECT 
    contacts.id,
    contacts.first_name,
    contacts.last_name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(field_values.field_id = 2, field_values.value, NULL)) AS email,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(field_values.field_id = 1, field_values.value, NULL)) AS field_1
FROM contacts 
LEFT JOIN field_values ON contacts.id = field_values.contact_id
GROUP BY contacts.id
ORDER BY email;.  -- it is optional, only include if you want to sort result by ascending emails.
```

Comment: This seemed to work with columns + ordering the fields. Nice job! Quick question, how slow would this query be with a say 5,000 contacts and 20 fields (thats 20 values per contact)?

Comment: Accepted! Yeah, I'm going to dynamically have it write the query based on the field columns to show, so thats not an issue. I'll run some speed tests with mock data.

Comment: One thing I noticed is, how do you WHERE these fields? so like `WHERE email = 'johndoe@mail.com'` currently that wont work of course

Comment: Simple solution would be, just make this result as derived table and use where condition on this result. `SELECT * FROM ( <above_query>) as temp WHERE <place_your_where_condition>`

Comment: Oh wow. That actually worked really simple. Thank you! You saved hours!

Comment: So I finally ran a test with larger datasets, 2,500 items with around 4-5 `GROUP_CONCAT` field columns and speed was about 1.2s per request. Each field added would increase by 100-200ms. I tried to do almost 15,000 items with about 4-5 fields and seeing speed hitting close to 10s per request. Because its pushing everything into a temp table, it's dumping ALL rows in the results. Im not sure if there is a way to speed this up even using indexing, as this is a really good solution, its too bad it cant be used with larger datasets. Any ideas?

Comment: I do notice, if I don't use the `LEFT JOIN` and use only `JOIN` I know that it will only work if the item id matches on both tables, but as long as its blank value if there isn't an item, it allows for speeds of 0.1s per request on 15,000 items and more fields hasn't significantly slowed it down yet.

Answer (score 0):

You may use pivoting logic here to turn out the email and city as separate columns:

```
SELECT
    c.id,
    c.first_name,
    c.last_name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN fv.field_id = 2 THEN fv.value END) AS email,
    MAX(CASE WHEN fv.field_id = 1 THEN fv.value END) AS city
FROM contacts c
LEFT JOIN field_values fv
    ON c.id = fv.contact_id
GROUP BY
    c.id,
    c.first_name,
    c.last_name;
```

Comment: What he said is `its more dynamic than a regular relationship join` so considering on what he said field_id can be not equal to either 1 or 2.

Comment: This did give me results in columns, but for some reason it doesnt allow for GROUP BY with email or city fields.

Comment: To address both comments, if the `field_id` doesn't equal 1 or 2, then that information is missing for a given contact, and there are no email or city columns.